# I want to have '' after sum

Tags: math-mode

[image]

```
\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(x_{k})
```

I want to change sth in this code to get sth like this image. I have problem where put ''.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375201/latex-sum-i-want-to-have-after-sum?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use

```
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{}'' f(x_{k})
```

Comment: thx :) I would have never guessed {}''

Comment: it's just that you now are double-priming the {}- but think about the notation, it is a bit nonstandard

Comment: With your method, the "double prime" symbols tend to be a bit too low. It's much better to use the command `\sideset` (see the other answer) for this reason. That said, your code reproduces the image that the OP posted exactly... :-)

Comment: really i - knew about `\sideset` - but i clearly forgot about it, in this case - the only thing i find a bit awkward is the space between the `n` and the `\sum`-symbol

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: This space is due to the possibility that the upper limit might exceed the width of the sum operator and thus overwrite the added marker.

Answer (score 17):

The `\sideset` command from the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package is probably more suitable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \[
    \sideset{}{''}\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(x_{k})
  \]
\end{document}
```